# Highlighting only selected regions in highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

H,

We are trying to use the following highmaps,

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed
```

My concern is we want the map to show names for only the regions we want and not all the regions as it's doing currently. We want names of regions like Delhi, Maharashtra only to be displayed and not all.

```js
$(function () {

    // Prepare demo data
    var data = [
        {
            "hc-key": "in-an",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-wb",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ld",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-5390",
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-py",
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-3464",
            "value": 5
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-mz",
            "value": 6
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-as",
            "value": 7
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-pb",
            "value": 8
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ga",
            "value": 9
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-2984",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-jk",
            "value": 11
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-hr",
            "value": 12
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-nl",
            "value": 13
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-mn",
            "value": 14
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-tr",
            "value": 15
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-mp",
            "value": 16
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ct",
            "value": 17
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ar",
            "value": 18
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ml",
            "value": 19
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-kl",
            "value": 20
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ap",
            "value": 21
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ka",
            "value": 22
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-mh",
            "value": 23
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-or",
            "value": 24
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-dn",
            "value": 25
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-dl",
            "value": 26
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-hp",
            "value": 27
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-rj",
            "value": 28
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-up",
            "value": 29
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ut",
            "value": 30
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-jh",
            "value": 31
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-ch",
            "value": 32
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-br",
            "value": 33
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-sk",
            "value": 34
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "in-tn",
            "value": 35
        }
    ];

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

        title : {
            text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
        },

        subtitle : {
            text : 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed.js">India with disputed territories</a>'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            name: 'Random data',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 500px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Regards,
Ayush

Comment: this question is kind of unclear... please explain more detailed. Do you mean when hovering the regions that not all of them turn green ?

Comment: @Dwza My concern is we want the map to show names for only the regions we want and not all the regions as it's doing currently. We want names of regions like Delhi, Maharashtra only to be displayed and not all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll illustrate two similar ways to do this, depending on the amount of points you want to show/not show the title for.

You could supply the name yourself, but only for the points you want to show it on, and then alter the `series.dataLabels.format` to use that name option instead. This would be best suited for showing few names or custom names. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ktbyba5/)):

```
var data = [
    {
        "hc-key": "in-an",
        "value": 0,
        "name": "My name"
    },
    //...
];

$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    //...

    series : [{
        //...
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.options.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

Alternatively, use a boolean in your `data` array to indicate that you want to hide that name and use a `formatter` to hide them. This is best suited for showing most of the default names and hiding a few. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ktbyba5/1/)):

```
var data = [
    {
        "hc-key": "in-an",
        "value": 0,
        "hide-name": true
    },
    //...
];

$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    //...

    series : [{
        //...
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.point.options["hide-name"])
                    return;
                return this.point.name;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Note that some name labels are hidden without specifying it here. This is because `allowOverlap` is set to `false` by default. Just add `series.dataLabels.allowOverlap: true` to show overlapping labels as well.